# fragment doesnt show the layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view

i have a **fragment** like this :

```
public class ContactFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);

        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
        }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_picker_activity, null);

            return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        }
        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
```

and **contacts_picker_activity** layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="this a test "
            android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

the problem is when i run my app, **onCreateView** method run but didnt show the layout.
i dont have any error in my logcat.

Comment: is my answer worked out?

Comment: ty ! but i used @shayan pourvatan answer :) (i saw it before your answer)

Comment: atleast give an upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_picker_activity, null);

            return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
  }
```

to

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {


          return inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_picker_activity, container , false);
 }
```

you need return your view that want to inflate in onCreateView

Comment: wow ! too fast answer :D it says must wait 5 more min to accept the answer :D thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)           
    {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_picker_activity, null);
        return v;
    }
```

You should return inflated `View`.

Answer (score 0):

Just return the inflated view.

```
public class ContactFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);

        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
        }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_picker_activity, null);

            return v;
        }
        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
```